# Cypress closing menu when clicking on submenu

Tags: angular, angular-material, automated-tests, cypress

I have been trying to check for a submenu. When I click on the primary menu, it works without fail. However, when I click on the secondary menu, it just closes the primary menu and the test fails.

```
cy.get('div.dropdown', {timeout:10000}).contains('Admin').click()

cy.get('div.subdropdown', {timeout:10000}).contains('Catalog Admin').should('be.visible')

cy.get('div.subdropdown').contains('Catalog Admin').click({ force: true })
```

That succeeds until it hits the click. I tried the force true after the first run failed. I even tried the following:

```
cy.get('div.subdropdown').contains('Catalog Admin').invoke('click')
```

I am unable to use .focus() and I'm at a loss. Each time I try something new. The primary dropdown closes instead of opening the secondary menu. Hover would work but it's not implemented yet. Nor did .invoke('mouseover'). I'm at a loss. I had a the same problem in other tests when clicking on other option in the primary menu to navigate to other areas. I ended up just adjusting my .visit to go directly to the page I needed to access. We are using Angular 8 components coded in Typescript.

Comment: I think you can do a mouseover before the click

cy.get('div.subdropdown').contains('Catalog Admin').trigger('mouseover', 'center').Click()

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, that two closed the menu instead of opening the submenu. I'm not sure if this is a problem when interacting with these Angular dropdowns or something else. All these methods work find with the selectors in our code, just not the dropdown menus.

Comment: Possibly related - I am trying to test mat-menu's at a small screen size and I noticed Cypress closing the menu between tests, but when I try to "re-open" the menu per test, that also seems to close them, or open/close them. Seems the relationship between the two is testy but I can't figure out where the failure is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Cypress Support, we were able to figure out how to do this. Since its a Material nested menu, this is what they have me doing and it works.

```
cy.get('div.subdropdown').contains('Catalog Admin').trigger('mouseenter')
```